# Sharing target Universal Apps Windows 10 approach

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, data-sharing

I am struggling with it for a few hours and can't find working solution. My app is a target app for sharing and the problem is when it's running and user wants to share content.

```
 protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
           await OnInitializeAsync();

            if (await CheckToken(args) != true) return;

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
            {
                if (await LoadData(args) != true) return;
            }

            var frame = new Frame();
            var navigationService = new NavigationService(_dispatcherService) { RootFrame = frame, };

            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            Window.Current.Activate();

            navigationService.Navigate<ShareViewModel>(args.ShareOperation);
        }
```

The problem is that I can't use frame from running application because I get an exception "marshalling thread ...." so I create a new frame and I assign it to Window.Current.Content. This works fine but the problem is when user finishes sharing. What should I do? It seems that I should assign previous frame to Window.Current.Content which was "overriden" by sharing target right? While I try to do it I get again "marshalling thread" exception. If I don't do it then I can't interact with my application because I get an exception that app is being closed. What is the proper scenario for being a sharing target?

Edit: I guess it's important to mention that I call **ReportStarted()** when I send message in ShareViewModel and **ReportCompleted()** when I am done.

Exception thrown when I try to assign frame back: 
**{"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.\r\n\r\nFailed to initialize the application's root visual"}**

Comment: Problem was the dispatcher which was overriden in OnWindowCreated method in App. And in one place I was using wrong dispatcher.

Comment: Can you share the updated code that works. I am also getting the same error while using share target.

Comment: [The answer I have posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36563896/2681948) at other question should also help you to solve the problem.

Comment: @mistyK can you please share your app? I'm currently struggling with the same problem

Comment: @Skynet094 done

Answer (score 1):

I'm pasting the solution which solved the issue. I think the key here is to use

> CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher

```
 protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            await OnInitializeAsync();

            if (await CheckToken(args) != true) return;

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
            {
                if (await LoadData(args) != true) return;
            }

            var frame = new Frame();
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            var dispatchService = new DispatcherService() { Dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher };
            var navigationService = new NavigationService(dispatchService) { RootFrame = frame };
            navigationService.Navigate<ShareViewModel>(args.ShareOperation);
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
```

Comment: can you please tell me what sort of thing are you coding in OnInitializeAsync?  Later today, I will share a 'share target' related problem I think you can help there.